# How to improve entropy on a router running Linux kernel 2.6.x without TRNG or RTC?

Tags: entropy

How could you improve entropy on a router running Linux kernel 2.6.x without TRNG or RTC ?

Comment: You can xor traffic that passes through the router into the entropy pool. You can never weaken entropy by xoring it with anything, and even if it's a weak source of entropy it's still one more thing that must be anticipated by an attacker.

Comment: @dingrite I strongly recommend against xoring. If you use a proper PRNG, it'll have an entropy injection interface, use it. You *can* weaken entropy by xoring if what you xor is derived from the entropy pool. Not if it's derived through a proper PRNG, but if you have a PRNG, use its entropy injection interface...

Comment: @Gilles xoring entropy with itself obviously wipes it out, do you have a source that explains how xoring it with a hash of itself impacts it negatively? afaik, all those entropy mixers fundamentally utilize hashing.

Comment: @dingrite The problem is doing it right. If you throw something together without understanding it, there's a risk of doing it wrong. Doing `state := state xor f(state)` will not weaken the entropy for most slapdash `f`, so the risk is relatively low, but it's still better not to take the risk at all and use the PRNG's interface. Recommending that people do something ad hoc is not a good idea.

Comment: Ironically, one thing to do (for kernel 2.6, not for newer kernels) is to keep the entropy pool intentionally low by periodically sending `/dev/random` to `/dev/null`. That causes the kernel to disable its "trickle threshold" and work harder at collecting entropy. Otherwise, it only collects one in every 4096 events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to *continually* feed entropy into the system for security, so long as the OS random number generator was strongly seeded *once*.

If you're unsure about the seeding history of the device, add some entropy. Take a photo of the sky with your mobile phone. Upload to your router and pipe it into `/dev/random`. That's [all the entropy you'll ever need](http://blog.cr.yp.to/20140205-entropy.html) on that particular device.

Seriously, there is so much nonsense surrounding entropy gathering out there it's almost funny. The Linux manual page for `/dev/random` is the cause of much of this pseudoscience; [it is simply wrong](https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/). The "entropy counters" provided by the kernel are ad-hoc estimates which are meaningless from a security perspective.

You can't "use up" or "lose" entropy on a modern OS. As long as your entropy is used only to seed a CSPRNG (which is true in even very old Linux), 256 bits of entropy is enough for every possible use case. If you *don't* believe that 256 bits is enough to generate a infinite stream of secure randomness, you'd better stop using AES in counter mode for encryption as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58315/discussion-on-answer-by-rmalayter-how-to-improve-entropy-on-a-router-running-lin).

Comment: There's one important step missing: reading back and updating the entropy at each boot. A typical router firmware doesn't write to its flash memory except on a configuration change, so it boots with no entropy.

Comment: What about the use of haveged ?

Comment: @uihdff the question says there is no real time clock, so I guess no high resolution timer is available either?

Comment: @rmalayter - The router is an Asus RT-AC88U so I would guess that it does not.

Comment: Was thinking of using an RTL-SDR device with rtl-entropy to strongly seed as early in the boot process as possible. If that were done, would it be necessary to save a random-seed at shutdown and write it back to the pools at startup ?

Comment: @uihdff if you have access to digitized but otherwise unframed wifi radio signals somehow, you might just be able to feed a seconds worth of whatever the antennas "hear" (including noise) into `/dev/random`. The well known random.org site uses atmospheric radio noise as its source.